# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead Jest error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my form input fields and the submit button using Jest+ Enzyme. I am getting the following error on my test:

> **Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**

What changes can I make in order to test my Form submit button along with the input group?

**This is my test**

```
it('handle submit', () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  expect(handleChange).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
   wrapper.find('Input').simulate('name', { target: { value: 'Hello' } });
   expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(wrapper.state().searchTerm).toBe('Hello');
  wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');
   expect(wrapper.state().searchTerm).toBe('Hello');
});
```

Comment: That means that your node was not found, so I'm guessing through what you've posted is that you need to search for InputTitle like this: wrapper.find('InputTitle'), because that's how you have named your component.

Comment: I tried with wrapper.find('InputTitle'), still the same error. @JeanAguilar . Any idea, what other steps could I do do get this error resolved?

Comment: You can add a console.log(wrapper.debug()) to see if your component is rendering correctly, also you can try to search the input html tag, wrapper.find('input') but try debugging the component to see if your input is actually there.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the issue because I did  console.log(wrapper.debug()) and it gave me the code which I have pasted in my code section above as "debug code". Could you please have a look at it? I tried wrapper.find('input') but it ain't giving any errors to that which means that it exists. Could you check the code and let me know if you find an issue? @JeanAguilar

Comment: Try to search for this  wrapper.find('input').at(0)  because your InputName component is an styled component, so you can't search for it, you need to find the dom element. In your debug I'm seeing two inputs that's why you need to specify that is the first input with the .at(0). I think that should do the trick.

Comment: That didn't do the trick either @JeanAguilar. Updated my test code for your reference, in case I am still doing something wrong

Comment: Could you also update the test as well?